# Is there a function in c that returns the index of a string in another string?

Tags: c, string, indexing, arrays

I have 2 char arrays

```
    char page=[4][5] = {{'a','b',' ','d','e'},  {'A',' ','C','D','E'},{'a','b','c','d','e'}, {'A','B','C','D','E'}};
    char word[5]="CDE";
```

I am trying to find the indices of the word "CDE" in `page`, namely 7 and 17.
Is there a function in C for this? Or a short way.
Something like,

```
    int indexlist[]=findindex(word, page);
```

Comment: Have you looked at `strstr`? It would have to be run "one line at a time" on your page.

Comment: You could zero-terminate `page` then use `strstr` to get the addresses.

Comment: strstr or the safe(r) strnstr

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
char page[4][5] = {{'a','b',' ','d','e'},  {'A',' ','C','D','E'},{'a','b','c','d','e'}, {'A','B','C','D','E'}};
    char word[5]="CDE";

// put all the characters in a single long string:
char buf[21];
memcpy(buf, &(page[0][0]), 20);
// and null terminate:
buf[20]='\0';
char *p;
p = buf;
while((p = strstr(p, word))!=NULL) {
  printf("found a match at offset of %d\n", (int)(p - buf));
  p+=strlen(word);
}
}
```

Output:

```
found a match at offset of 7
found a match at offset of 17
```

Comment: Yes, I think the copy to `buf` is the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing in the standard library is `strstr`:

```
char str1[] = "A CDE";
char str2[] = "CDE";

char *p = strstr( str1, str2 );
```

`p` now points to the `C` in `str1` (`&str1[2]`).